# Replace string with single quotes in it with another string SQL

Tags: sql

I have a value in a column (call the column c1) like below:

```
'there it is' is what she said
```

and I would like to replace it with:

```
'there it is plus two' is what she said
```

but having a hard time.

```
Using replace(c1
    , ''there it is' is what she said'
    , ''there it is plus two' is what she said')
```

Gives me "Incorrect syntax near there".

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Azure synapse/Sql Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting `'` inside string `''`:

```
replace(c1
    , '''there it is'' is what she said'
    , '''there it is plus two'' is what she said')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to double single quotes in a string:

```
  replace(c1,
          '''there it is'' is what she said'
          '''there it is plus two'' is what she said'
         )
```